# File is not a zip file --> Won't load excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to load my file (which isn't a zip file) using the following piece of code:

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('US.xlsx')

But I recieve an immediate error: "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"

I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: Your file is corrupted; do you have any way of retrieving a fresh copy of it?  (A .xslx file actually *is* a ZIP file, you wouldn't normally treat it as one, but any software that wants to access the contents must necessarily unzip it to do anything.)

Comment: .xlsx usually ARE zip files. If yours isn't, then that's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Pandas` library? `xlsx = pd.read_excel('US.xlsx')`.. As @Soren has mentioned .xlsx files are compressed by default, try Pandas and see what the error is

Comment: When I try to read one of the worksheets/tabs in a new excel file, I get the following error: "BadZipFile: Bad magic number for file header". The file itself, is huge, could that be an issue itself?

Comment: https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-read-an-excel-file-with-extension-xlsx-with-pandas-in-python-/   : import pandas as pd  df = pd.read_excel ('../read_excel_file_with_python.xlsx')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.